# Gratis Windows app to mute all programs but one (like SoundSource for Mac)

Tags: windows, gratis, vlc

I generally mute my laptop. I generally have multiple browsers open, with multiple tabs.

Inevitably, when I want to watch a movie on my laptop, one of those dozens/hundreds of tabs has a video running, with sound, and, when they stop, they just run another.  Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh!!!!!

Is there any solution?

- I use VLC to play video, so a plug-in for that that mutes everything else, woudl be fine
- a gratis Windows app to mute all programs but one would be equally acceptable

For instance, a gratis Windows version of [SoundSource for mac](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/)

[image]

> Control audio on a per-app basis, adjusting the volume and output device for individual apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html

Mute all applications (SoundVolumeView.exe /Mute AllAppVolume), then unmute one specific (SoundVolumeView.exe /Unmute your_app.exe).

Comment: Wah! How could I forget NorSoft? Their apps are awesome. I will verify this & get right back to you.  Thanx a 1,000,000